# Dynamically set the initialization, condition, and in/decrementation of for-loops

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

At the moment, I am having to write out multiple `for-loops` which all do the same task, with the differences being in the initialization, condition, and the de/incrementation within the `for-loops` themselves.

Here is an example of something similar I have so far:

```
if(some_bool_condition)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        // do something
    }
} 
else
{
    for(int i = 10; i >= 5; i--)
    {
        // do same thing
    }
}
```

Is there a trick or technique I can use to merge these `for-loops` together?

Comment: For this particular example you could probaly use `10-i`, because the *count* happens to be equal. However, in general you may want to be Friendly To Other Readers (which may very well be *you* in a month).

Comment: The first for loop has 5 iterations and the second has 6. Is that intended? It makes it harder..

Comment: @Jongware the first has i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (5 values) the second has 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 (6 .values)

Comment: My actual implementation isn't literally this, and has more loops, but good suggestions.

Comment: @rpattiso: I should have counted on my fingers  The more reason not to Improve Through Obfuscation!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int start = 0;  // or some other value
int end   = 5;  // ditto
int delta = 1;  // 1 or -1
for ( int i = start; i != end; i += delta )
{
    // do something
}
```

Of course the delta has to be choosen carefully so that `i` actually reaches `end` exactly.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good idea. Can't accept answer for another 9 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. No worries, I can wait :)

Comment: One can even make the loop a function with start/end/delta as input arguments and call that function with different set of arguments. However in this case, loop conditions are no longer known at compile time, hence gives compiler a hard time trying to optimize the loop. The solution is simple: inline the function to give compiler more hint on the loop count of each call of the function, at the price of multiple copies of machine code. If the function is long, then this is very likely against most coding standards, but sometime it's worth it.

Answer (score 5):

Make  do someting be a function.  Pass the start value,  test, and increment/decrement value as arguments.  Do the for loop in the function.